# If I create 1 library do I need to create multiple views

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

If I have a subsite library that contains all documents that pertain to meetings, clients, agreements, presentations, and training documents, thus it appears I need to create 5 views.

Note I do have 5 content types, but the content type filter does not automatically hide the columns not associated with the content type.  Doesn't it make sense to create 5 libraries ?  I could end up with more content types and this seems like a pain to create so many views requiring de-selection of columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the columns in a content type so when you select it, the fields that are not associated are hidden.

I suggest creating views instead but if there are a lot of documents in that library then it is time to separate the documents by library (meetings, agreements etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You might be helped by the EditView Bookmarklet you can add to your browser.

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Drag_Drop_Columns_in_the_EditView_Page

It makes editting Views a breeze, *well.. a bit more 2015 than that 2001 User Interface*

[image: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/ViewEditDragDrop.gif]